# Ansible multiple hosts for a specific playbook?

Tags: ansible, hosts

normally in ansible you always define a specific host for a specific playbook. But what is if I want to run a playbook for multiple hosts?

For a bit more clarity: I have following groups:

- Webservers
- Dev Clients

and following playbooks:

- install main software
- install certbot
- install nginx
- install vscode

For obvious reasons for sure the nginx playbook should have the entry: `hosts: Webservers` but what is with the `main software` playbook. This playbook should include both hosts.

In the end I want to have many different playbooks and groups and the only thing I wanna execute is: `ansible-playbook ~/playbooks/webservers.yml` and this triggers: "main software, certbot, nginx..." via includes. But this doesn't work without editing the hosts section of every playbook that is included in the `webservers.yml`.

Is it possible to tell a playbook that it should run on the hosts from the main-playbook which has included it?
like: webservers.yml -> hosts -> nginx.yml -> run on all clients which are entered in webservers.yml?

Does somebody of you has an idea? Or is this just not realizable with ansible?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

You could use `include` module with `when` statement using `group_names` var as below:

`webservers.yml`

```yaml
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: Include Main Software playbook
      include: main_software.yml

    - name: Include Nginx playbook
      include: nginx.yml
      when: "'webservers' in {{ group_names }}"

    - name: Include Vscode playbook
      include: vscode.yml
      when: "'DevClients' in {{ group_names }}"
```

Remember `main_software.yml`, `nginx.yml` and `vscode.yml` playbooks must have a list of `tasks` not a `play`.

Comment: Hi, first thanks for you're answer,
but this won't fix my problem. If I will do it with when, sure the main install playbook will get called but it will rollout for all machines that are defined under the specific "hosts" section. So if i run ```ansible-playbook ~/playbooks/webservers.yml``` it will also rollout machines in the "dev clients" group. Because they are also under  ```main_software.yml hosts:```.

Comment: Hi @gary lopez thanks for your answer it solved my problem can you please confirm me what is this called "group_names" is this magic variable or something else, if it is then can you refer me any resource to know more about this & other magic variables which exists